# Myoware reading multiple fingers?

Tags: sensors

So I have recently been trying to use the Myoware Muscle sensor to control an 3d printed arm, but it is only able to read the muscle of the entire arm. Is there anyway i could make the Myoware sensor read different fingers at the same time?

Comment: I don't think so. I have already a lot of trouble to have a consistent results with Myoware. The muscles for the fingers are smaller and a little deeper. I think that you can not use the muscles to measure motion of the fingers. You need to measure the mechanical motion or bending of the fingers, for example with a glove with stretch sensors.

Comment: Ooo ok then thx for the help, i'll see what i can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our MyoWare sensor is a single channel EMG sensor and should only be used to detect a single muscle at a time. BUT, if you have 5 sensors, then you can indeed use them to measure each finger's flexion or extension individually. It would take 10 sensors to do both flexion and extension of all your fingers.

However, keep in mind that there are many muscle groups on top of each other in the forearm (e.g. finger muscles, wrist muscles, forearm rotation muscles) and the MyoWare uses surface electrodes. The sensor will detect the activity of any muscle(s) that get activated under the area of the electrodes and you could get a lot of cross-talk between these muscles. For example, the muscles that control your wrist are under the muscles that control your fingers. Any activation of your wrist muscles when trying to measure the finger muscles would cause the sensor to falsely register activity for your finger muscles.

[image]

If you are thinking of using it to detect finger position, I would advise using a flex sensor or something similar than a muscle sensor. Muscle sensor sensors are usually used to detect force or as an on/off switch given a threshold value to activate the switch.

Comment: I would also recommend using the MyoWare Cable Shield with electrodes smaller than the standard 1" ones that are usually sold along side the sensor. This would help you target smaller muscles without as much cross-talk from adjacent muscles.

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind thx